# Replacing words in a table automatically

Tags: tables, french

I am currently working on a paper for an economics course. I need to produce, among other things, summary statistics. As I am working on Stata, I picked the sutex command and outputted the tables in tex formats.

Everything looks fine, except for a small detail: I need to produce a document in French. I can change the title and variable names in Stata directly, what remains unchanged are the headers (mean, std. dev., etc.).

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: without seeing the generated tex hard to say, can you not customise the headings from stata? (they do not come from latex, presumably)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Google suggests the format is as below. If it really isn't possible to change these headings from the sutex that is generating them, you could define `\texbf` to do the job. (Sorry about my French:-)

However unless you have thousands of these, I'd just edit the generated tex by hand rather than doing this, also I would change the `c` column type in the numeric columns and replace by a decimal aligned column, `D` from `dcolumn` package or `S` from `siunitx`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldtextbf\textbf
\def\textbf#1{\oldtextbf{\def\tmp{#1}%
\ifx\tmp\bfV Vrbll in French%
\else\ifx\tmp\bfM Mn in French%
\else\ifx\tmp\bfS std dev in French%
\else #1\fi\fi\fi}}

\def\bfV{Variable}
\def\bfM{Mean}
\def\bfS{Std. Dev.}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering \caption{Summary statistics \label{sumstat}}
\begin{tabular}{l c c  }\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \textbf{Mean}
 & \textbf{Std. Dev.} \\ \hline
id & 100.5 & 57.879  \\
female & 0.545 & 0.499  \\
race & 3.43 & 1.039  \\
ses & 2.055 & 0.724  \\
schtyp & 1.16 & 0.368  \\
prog & 2.025 & 0.690  \\
read & 52.23 & 10.253  \\
write & 52.775 & 9.479  \\
math & 52.645 & 9.368  \\
science & 51.85 & 9.901  \\
socst & 52.405 & 10.736  \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{200}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: example from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/latex/summary_stata.htm

Comment: This works perfectly well - thanks. For the benefit of other people, this must be placed AFTER your uploaded the linguistic packages or, else, special characters won't be displayed properly. Also, for curious minds, "mean" is "moyenne" and "std. dev." is "écart-type" and variable remains unchanged.